# Linux SCP defining destination port

Tags: linux, scp

How can I specify a port for the destination ip?  When I do `scp -p 0000` it still tries to connect on port 22, not the one I'm specifying.

```
scp svn_backup.tgz user@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:/path/to/new/svn/
```

Comment: You can find great information reading manual pages. `man scp`, for example.

Comment: If in doubt, `--help` or `man` will probably give you the answer.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Capital "P".

```
$ scp -P 12345 svn_backup.tgz user@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:/path/to/new/svn/
```

See `$ man scp` for more details.

Comment: Hooray for consistency!

Comment: @David: `scp` was designed to imitate `rcp`, and rcp used `-p` to "preserve file times and modes". See `man scp`.

Answer (score 4):

It's also noteworthy that the port specification must come *before* the file name, i.e.:

```
scp svn_backup.tgz -P 12345 user@xxx.xxx.xx.xxx:/path/to/new/svn/
```

***won't** work.